# How to get every API response using angular interceptor to build common functionality

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to check one common property status is true or false (**"isNotificationAvailable": true/false**) in every API hit, Based on this property true/false I have to build some business logic. Kindly help me to write the one interceptor so that I don't need to check this condition in every API response. which will help me to avoid duplicate code.

Please find one sample API response below.

```
{
   "isSuccessful":true,
   "message":null,
   "isNotificationAvailable": true/false,
   "data":{
      "states":[
         {
            "code":1,
            "name":"Alabama"
         },
         {
            "code":2,
            "name":"Alaska"
         },
         {
            "code":3,
            "name":"Arizona"
         },
         {
            "code":14,
            "name":"Illinois"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this steps**

1. Using `ng generate interceptor INTERCEPTOR_NAME` (More details can be found here
   https://angular.io/cli/generate)
2. Add the interceptor into your `app.module.ts` into the providers array, like this:

> ```
> providers: [{
>         provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
>         useClass: YOUR_INTERCEPTOR,
>         multi: true
>     }]
> ```

3. Then into your httpInterceptor, in te intercept method just write

> ```
> return next.handle(request)
>   .pipe(map<HttpEvent<any>, any>((evt: HttpEvent<any>) => {
>         if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
>           //Do your stuff. To take the body you have an example below.
>           const x = (evt as HttpResponse<any>).body.isNotificaitonAvailable;
>         }
>         return evt;
>       }));
> ```

For more info about the http interceptor check this out https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have something like a `NotificationService` which handle UI updates depending on the response, I would create a HttpInterceptor that updates the service after each API response.

**NotificationService**

```
// if components need access to this boolean, use a Behavior Subject exposed as an Observable that components can subscribe to
public notificationAvailable$$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
public notificationAvailable$ = this.notificationAvailable$$.asObservable();

showNotification(data: any): void {
    // either update the BehaviorSubject so that any subscribers are aware
    this.notificationAvailable.next(true);
    // or do something within the service to handle notifications
    this.doSomethingWithNotifications();
}
```

**NotificationInterceptor**

```
export class NotificationInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService) {}

    public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      return next.handle(req).pipe(
          tap((resp) => {
              if (resp instanceof HttpResponse and resp.body.isNotificationAvailable) {              
                this.notificationService.showNotification();
             }
                  
          })
      );

    }

}
```

You'll need to make sure you provide the new HttpInterceptor in your `app.module.ts` as well so that this service is recognized. Additionally, if you go the Subject route, you'll want a method in your NotificationService that toggles that boolean back to `false` after some action has been taken.

[HttpInterceptor Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor#usage-notes)